# How to detect if a message contains the inline keyboard

Tags: telegram-bot

Telegram bot performs some tasks with messages in channels. It should skip messages with inline buttons (for example, with voting buttons).

Is there a way to identify if the posted message contains the inline keyboard or not?

[Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) object seems not to contain anything like that. [editReplyMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) 
can only replace the keyboard...

To make it more clear.

This is ordinal message:
[image]

This is message with buttons:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

How does bot handle a messages?
You must check type in `Update` object.

upd:

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler

def start(bot, update):
    print(update)
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("one", callback_data='1'),
                InlineKeyboardButton("two", callback_data='2')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton("tree", callback_data='3')]]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', reply_markup=reply_markup)


def button(bot, update):
    print(update)
    query = update.callback_query
    bot.edit_message_text(text="Your choose: %s" % query.data,
        chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
        message_id=query.message.message_id)


up = Updater('***TOKEN***')
up.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
up.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
up.start_polling()
```

return diffrent

message:

{message: {message_id: 20, new_chat_members: [], new_chat_member: None, date: 0000000001, delete_chat_photo: False, 
from: {id: 000000005, username: username, first_name: name, language_code: en-US}, entities: [{offset: 0, length: 6, 
type: bot_command}], chat: {id: 000000005, username: username, first_name: name, type: private}, new_chat_photo: [],
group_chat_created: False, photo: [], supergroup_chat_created: False, text: /start, channel_chat_created: False}, update_id: 000000051}

inline:

{callback_query: {chat_instance: -0000000000000000060, message: {message_id: 21, new_chat_members: [],
new_chat_member: None, date: 1505211901, delete_chat_photo: False, from: {id: 000000005, username: botname,
first_name: test}, entities: [], chat: {id: 000000005, username: username, first_name: name, type: private},
new_chat_photo: [], group_chat_created: False, photo: [], supergroup_chat_created: False, text: Please choose:,
channel_chat_created: False}, data: 2, id: 0000000000000000094, from: {id: 000000005, username: username,
first_name: name, language_code: en-US}}, update_id: 000000005}

Comment: The "getUpdate" method returns me "Upadate" object with filled "channel_post" field (for channels) that contains object "Message". Nothing else could be checked there, as far as I see. :(

Comment: are you checked difference between `inline` and `not inline` objects?

i edited post for small example

Comment: That's not I'm talking about: no callback. I'd updated the post with samples. I should identify if the message that is posted to channel (by other members) contains inline keyboard (second sample) or not (first sample). And yes, I use the same python bot engine. :)

Comment: do you mean, a many bots in channel will send different messages and your bot will identify type of message?
keyboards are don't included to query if not pressed.
as i know, it's possible by client but not by bot.

Comment: Yep, there are several bots there. I.e. users some time make posts via bots to embed buttons like voting or subscription.